# How to Send Spoiler Tag as HTML to Teams Channel via Graph API

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

We have tried to upload HTML content to Teams channel and we are trying to upload Spoiler Tag as HTML to the team channel message, we are getting issues, Please tell us how to create a spoiler tag HTML to the teams channel via API

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like MS Teams supports a spoiler tag... In markdown it supports these: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-microsoft-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

Hopefully someone else can provide a better answer...